# Find a Matrix A for insect population

Tags: matrices

Consider an insect species in which no individuals live beyond 3 days. The population is divided into four age groups labelled by *n* = 0, 1, 2 and 3. Assume that only the second (*n*=1) and third (*n*=2) groups can reproduce. For each group *n*, let $b_n$ be the birth rate and $d_n$ be the death rate.

How do I find a matrix **A** such that **P**$(t+1)$ = **AP**$(t)$ with

**P**$(t)$ = \begin{bmatrix}P_0(t)\\P_1(t)\\P_2(t)\\P_3(t)\end{bmatrix}where $P_n(t)$ denotes the population size of age group *n* at day *t*.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the insects reproduce asexually, so that a single second or third-group insect can give rise to a single first-group insect with probability $b_1$ or $b_2$, accordingly?

Comment: I think it does not matter, it is already part of the measure of the rate $b$ itself, a sexual reproduction would lead to to a rate $2b$ with $P/2$ males and $P/2$ females and is equivalent to an asexual reproduction. And even if the number of males and females are not equal, I guess the methodology for measuring $b$ already takes that into account to make an asexual model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would express it as below :

$\begin{cases}
P_0(t+1)=b_1P_1(t)+b_2P_2(t)\\
P_1(t+1)=(1-d_0)P_0(t)\\
P_2(t+1)=(1-d_1)P_1(t)\\
P_3(t+1)=(1-d_2)P_2(t)\\
\end{cases}$ giving the following matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b_1 & b_2 & 0 \\ 1-d_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1-d_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-d_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$